# Loading python envvars without using `source`

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I am looking for a solution to loading an `envvars.sh` file within a django application. I would prefer to do this within the settings module and keep a file outside of it. Here is what I currently have:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def source_envvars(fname='envvars.sh'):
    """Equivalent of `$ source {fname}` with lines in the form of `export key=value`"""
    envvars = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, fname)
    if not os.path.exists(envvars): return
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('export '):
                line = line.strip()
                key = line.split('=')[0].split()[1]
                value = line.split('=')[1].strip('"\'')
                os.environ[key] = value


if not os.environ.get('DB_HOST'): source_envvars()
# rest of settings.py file...
```

Are there any downsides of using this approach? I know this doesn't support complicated bash-type exports, but all I have are basic exports of the form:

```
export DB_HOST=rds.amazon.com/12345
```

Does the above approach properly instantiate all the variables, or does it seem to be missing something or insecure in some way or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation can only handle fixed formats. A shell script can potentially have conditional statements and loops, etc., none of which can be handled properly without actually sourcing it through a shell.

A more robust method is therefore to use `subprocess.check_output` to run a shell with `.` to source `envvars.sh` and the `env` command to output the environment variables, the output of which can be then used to create a generator expression to update `os.environ` with:

```
os.environ.update(
    line.rstrip().split('=', 1)
    for line in subprocess.check_output(['sh', '-c', '. envvars.sh; env']).splitlines()
)
```

Comment: Two questions on this. (1) Why do you need to `. envvars.sh;` and not just `envvars.sh`? and (2) Also, why do you need the `-c` command on this?

Comment: Further to the above, why wouldn't just doing `sh envvars.sh; env` work?

Comment: I use `-c` to run multiple commands in one shell session in order for the environment variables set by the shell script to be retrievable by `env`. Running `sh envvars.sh; env` will not work because `envvars.sh` would then be executed inside its own shell, so the environment variables set within that shell won't be accessible by `env`. I use `.` to source the script for the current shell to avoid spawning a separate shell, for the same reasons as above.